# Apache mod_rewrite rules ignored when request uri contains known extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

These are my rules:

```
# Rewrite rules
RewriteRule    ^$ path/to/webroot/index.php   [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) path/to/webroot/index.php [L]
```

Which I would expect to rewrite all requests to: **path/to/webroot/index.php** (please note, I've simplified this for demonstration purposes)

**Tests:**

```
Request               Response      Result
/test                 200           [PASSED]  
/another_test         200           [PASSED]

/index.html           404           [FAILED]
/index.htmlXX         200           [PASSED]

/test.css             404           [FAILED]
/test.cssXX           200           [PASSED]

/index.php            200           [PASSED]
```

**tl;dr: %.html & %.css fail, everything else passes.**

It appears that requests that contain extensions the server understands (html, css, ...), the rewrites get ignored. The one exception in my test being .php, which the server redirects and serves correctly.

Unfortunately I don't currently have access to the server logs.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: "Am I doing it wrong?" -- no. Has to be some other settings/rewrite rules elsewhere. Server log (especially rewrite debug log) is must have here (latest 2.4 version: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).

Comment: Yup, thought that might be the case. I have SSH access but everything is on lock down. Waiting to hear from admin.

Comment: On another hand -- please provide your real rules (since you have said they are simplified) -- maybe you have a rule or condition that tells Apache to ignore requests to existing files (or files with specific extensions or in specific folders) -- quite common approach with your "redirect all to index.php" rule)

Comment: By simplifying I just replaced $1 with index.php. My actual rule looks like: `RewriteRule (.*) path/to/webroot/$1 [L]` then I do some processing inside webroot. I've removed that for now to simplify the problem.

Comment: rule 2 covers rule 1, hence R1 is redundant.  R2 is a universal wildcard so if it isn't firing then it most be covered by another rule.  Can't help any further without a full .htaccess which exhibits this prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I apologise for wasting anyone's time on this question. I wasn't fully aware of the server setup when I posted this question. I won't go into the details but I will post the answer because hopefully it might help others who run into the same situation.

The 'problem' arose as Nginx is being used to the serve the static assets - js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|etc|etc... and hence the mod_rewrite rules are not being applied to any requests with these file extensions.

Obviously the solution is to create rewrite rules for the assets using [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, if the files **does exists**, then your rewriterules are not applied. This often comes from `Multiviews` option.

Solution to try:

- disable MultiViews in .htaccess: `Options -MultiViews`
- remove MultiViews from default config

Comment: Thank you for your input - I had tried these options to no avail. See my answer for the real 'problem'.